# Defer exceptions in multiple rake tasks

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task

I am new to Rake.

I am writing a series of tests to validate data stored in YAML files.  Each test is a separate rake task.

My problem is this:  I would like a single exception to be raised at the end in the case of multiple test failures.

It seems like an easy problem but I'm afraid after much googling I can't find a clean way to do it.

One solution might be to use multiple begin, rescue blocks and a global variable?

```
status = 0

desc 'task 1'
task :task_1 do
  begin
    raise if something_is_bad
  rescue
    puts "something is bad"
    status += 1
  end
end

desc 'task 2'
task :task_2 do
  begin
    raise if something_else_is_bad
  rescue
    puts "something else is bad"
    status += 1
  end
end

desc 'default task'
task :default do
  Rake::Task['task_1'].execute
  Rake::Task['task_2'].execute
  if status
    raise "There were errors"
  end
end
```

That seems to result in too much repetition of begin, rescue.

Another solution might be to have an error handling method?

```
status = 0

def handle_failure(status, message)
  status += 1
  puts message
end

desc 'task 1'
task :task_1 do
  handle_failure(status, "something is bad") if something_is_bad
end

desc 'task 2'
task :task_2 do
  handle_failure(status, "something else is bad") if something_else_is_bad
end

desc 'default task'
task :default do
  Rake::Task['task_1'].execute
  Rake::Task['task_2'].execute
  if status
    raise "There were errors"
  end
end
```

I still feel there must be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is roughly how I would go about it, given your requirements.

```
desc 'task 1'
task :task_1 do
  if something_is_bad
    puts "something is bad"
    raise
  end
end



task :default do
  failed = false
  %W(task_1 task_2).each do |task|
    begin
      Rake::Task[task].execute
    rescue
      failed = true
    end
  end
  puts "One of the tasks failed!" if failed
end
```